# C# - LINQ Lambda expression using GroupBy - Why nested validations are so inefficient?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-core, lambda

I had a bad day tried to improve the performance of the next query in C#, using Entity Framework (The information is stored in a SQL Server, and the structure use a Code First approach - But this does not matter at this time):

#### Bad performance query:

```
var projectDetail = await _context
    .ProjectDetails
    .Where(pd => projectHeaderIds.Contains(pd.IdProjectHeader))
    .Include(pd => pd.Stage)
    .Include(pd => pd.ProjectTaskStatus)
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.IdProjectHeader, g.IdStage, g.Stage.StageName })
    .Select(pd => new
    {
        pd.Key.IdProjectHeader,
        pd.Key.IdStage,
        pd.Key.StageName,
        TotalTasks = pd.Count(),
        MissingCriticalActivity = pd.Count(t => t.CheckTask.CriticalActivity && t.ProjectTaskStatus.Score != 100) > 0,
        Score = Math.Round(pd.Average(a => a.ProjectTaskStatus.Score), 2),
        LastTaskCompleted = pd.Max(p => p.CompletionDate)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

After some hours, I figured out the problem and I was able to fix the performance (Instead to takes more than 4 minutes, now, **the new query takes only 1-2 seconds**):

#### New query

```
var groupTotalTasks = await _context
    .ProjectDetails
    .Where(pd => projectHeaderIds.Contains(pd.IdProjectHeader))
    .Select(r => new
    {
        r.IdProjectHeader,
        r.CompletionDate,
        r.IdStage,
        r.ProjectTaskStatus.Score,
        r.CheckTask.CriticalActivity,
        r.Stage.StageName
    })
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.IdProjectHeader, g.IdStage, g.StageName })
    .Select(pd => new
    {
        pd.Key.IdProjectHeader,
        pd.Key.IdStage,
        pd.Key.StageName,
        TotalTasks = pd.Count(),
        MissingCriticalActivity = pd.Count(r => r.CriticalActivity && r.Score != 100) > 0,
        Score = Math.Round(pd.Average(a => a.Score), 2),
        LastTaskCompleted = pd.Max(p => p.CompletionDate)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

The steps to improve the query was the following:

- Avoid `nested validations` (Like `Score`, that use the `MainQuery.ProjectTaskStatus.Score` to calculate the `average`)
- Avoid `Include` in the queries
- I used a `Select` to only get the information that I will use after in the `GroupBy`.

Those changes fixed my issue, but, **why?**

...and, still, exists another way to improve this query?

What are the reasons specifically to use of nested validations makes the query extremely slow?
*The other changes make more sense to me.*

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior .Net Core 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently read that whenever EF Core 2 ran into anything that it couldn't produce a SQL Query for, it would switch to in-memory evaluation. So the first query would basically be pulling all of your ProjectDetails out of the database, then doing all the grouping and such in your application's memory. That's probably the biggest issue you had.

Using `.Include` had a big impact in that case, because you were including a bunch of other data when you pulled out all those ProjectDetails. It probably has little to no impact now that you've avoided doing all that work in-memory.

They realized the error in their ways, and [changed the behavior to throw an exception in cases like that starting with EF Core 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

To avoid problems like this in the future, you can upgrade to EF Core 3, or just be really careful to ensure Entity Framework can translate everything in your query to SQL.

Comment: Make sense, but the nested evaluations are the bottleneck in my query. But absolutely I will make the migration to .Net 3 to avoid any further issue.